# Type Mismatch error for integer cell value and decimal value variable

Tags: excel, vba

Hi please find below vb code

```
        match_points = CInt(Sheet3.Cells(winning_row, name_col) * x_factor)
        Sheet5.Cells(final_row, final_col) = match_points
```

x_factor is a decimal value and my cell value is integer. After running it is giving me type mismatch error. Kindly request to help. what code should be written so that it will accept value.

Comment: 1. Try `Sheet3.Cells(winning_row, name_col).Value`. Sometimes properties need be specified rather than rely on the default for a `Cells` object. 2. You may have accidentally put a number in but formatted it as text. 3. Use 'CLng` in place of 'CInt` just in case you are receiving a result >32K.

Answer (score 0):

according to the msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Cells method returns a **range** of cells or a single cell.. ins hort: a complex type and not the value. how about?

```
match_points = CInt(Sheet3.Cells(winning_row, name_col).Value * x_factor)
```